# Postgres - UPDATE a column multiple times with the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `post` table which has a `title` and a `description`.

My goal is to clean the description by applying a set of rules. For simplicity let's say that I'd like to apply following rules:

```
REPLACE "H" with "Z"
REPLACE "Z" with "C"
REPLACE "C" with "X"
```

So if I have the string "Hello world", the output would be "Xello world" after applying the three rules.

```
Hello world -> Zello world -> Cello world -> Xello world
```

I know I can achieve this using 3 independent update queries

```
UPDATE post
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'H', 'Z');

UPDATE post
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'Z', 'C');

UPDATE post
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'C', 'X');
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want. Maybe I need a procedure? a function? store the middle result in a variable?

I am using Postgres 12.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your requirement, what you want is all the characters `'H'`, `'Z'` and `'C'` to be finally replaced by `X`.
You can do it with the function `TRANSLATE()`:

```
UPDATE post
SET description = translate(description, 'HZC', 'XXX');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can nest the replace calls:

```
UPDATE post
  SET description = replace(replace(replace(description, 'H', 'Z'), 'Z', 'C'), 'C', 'X')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
UPDATE post
SET description = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(description, 'H', 'Z'), 'Z', 'C'), 'C', 'X');
```